# Conditionally concatenate in reducer using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I try to conditionally concat in my reducer, I have an array objects and I want to concatenate only if value not exist in my reducer. 
If value exists nothing must happen.
I use lodash and I tried with `_.uniqBy` like this :

```
_.uniqBy(arr1.concat(val1), 'id');
```

This does not work.

#### Example of my reducer

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1, name:'alex'}, {id:2, name:'taylor'}]
const val1 = {id:1, name:'alex'};

const reducer = {
    finalArr: arr1.concat(val1)
}

console.log('Reducer', reducer)
```

[jsFiddle linkk](https://jsfiddle.net/b8L8rv4d/)

#### Required output :

```
[{id:1, name:'alex'}, {id:2, name:'taylor'}]
```

Because val1 ({id:1, name:'alex'}) already exists in the array.

Comment: what is your required output?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating the arrays, and removing duplicates using `_.uniqBy()` works fine.

Example:

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1, name:'alex'}, {id:2, name:'taylor'}]
const val1 = {id:1, name:'alex'};

const result = _.uniqBy(arr1.concat(val1), 'id');

console.log('Reducer', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, it's better to use [`_.unionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unionBy) which creates an array of unique values, in order, from all given arrays:

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1, name:'alex'}, {id:2, name:'taylor'}]
const val1 = {id:1, name:'alex'};

const result = _.unionBy(arr1, val1, 'id');

console.log('Reducer', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried, what you have done , it is working perfectly fine .

You can try this as well,

*.uniqBy(*.concat(arr1, val1), 'id')